# What is a word that describes the start or opening of a conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

What is a word that describes the start or opening of a conversation either with a friend, a stranger, in a formal situation like a business meeting or in a court?

I am looking for something with a meaning along the lines of an ice-breaker, perhaps?

---

Answer (score 2):

Make a conversation *strike up*.

> **strike up**: to initiate, begin: *to strike up a conversation*

You can also *kick off* a conversation.

> [kick off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kick+off?show=0&t=1401270602): to start out, begin

Alternately, consider [**conversation starter**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Conversation%20Starter).

Answer (score 2):

A [*conversation opener*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_opener).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

I like how Dr. John Gottman calls these a "bid for connection".  Or just a bid.  Bids can be verbal like, "You would not believe the day I had".  Or they can be nonverbal, like, sighing, or sitting next to the person, or sending them a picture or link they might like.

Answer (score 0):

[Conversational gambit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gambit) might be one possibility.

> A remark intended to open a conversation.